# polymer dart vs polymer js: does it matter when using the component?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I want to build a polymer component.
I can build it using Javascript.
I can build it using Dart.

For the person using it (me, someone else), does it make a difference or is the polymer packaging hiding all the magic inside?

Answer (score 6):

When you build it in JavaScript you should be able to use it in Dart. There are some problems and it might need some manual tweaking to make it work. This is work in progress and will become easier soon (for example bower support for Darts `pub`).

There is a package that helps generating a wrapper for Polymer.js elements to be easily used in Dart https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/custom_element_apigen

When you build it in Dart you can use it only in a Dart application but not in a JavaScript app.
This may change in the future but not to soon I guess but as I understand it this is work in progress.

Comment: Even if you run dart2js?

Comment: You need to run dart2js on the entire app. You can't dart2js parts that you reuse somewhere (or at least it's impractical). If you disable tree shaking and minification you might be able to use it from JavaScript (not tested, just guessing) but you get huge output. You can make the methods/fields available to JavaScript but you have to do this for each method/field using dart-js-interop (not tested, just guessing this might work). And you also get the entire dart2js boilerplate for each part that you build to JavaScript (about 200k each time). This way of using Dart is just not yet supported.