# Import JavaScript Polymer element to Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

How do I import a Polymer element made with JS to Dart? Is it possible to use one automatically or do I have to translate its internal JS to Dart?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the package https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/custom_element_apigen which is used to generate wrappers for core- and paper-elements.

See also

- [Is there a port of google-youtube webcomponent for Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931304)
- [polymer dart vs polymer js: does it matter when using the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274450)